# What red wine goes with fish?

Tags: fish, wine

I have been wanting to try a nice red wine with fish and I'm not a huge fan of white.
Recently I have been drinking Pinot Noir. But I'm looking for one more suited for fish (I know this isn't traditional)

Comment: What fish? They have different flavor and strength, I think this will probably affect the choice.

Comment: After viewing all of your questions and answers together, they seem like self-promotion. As they don't have much content otherwise, and you put no disclosure, this is against our faq (http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) and I deleted them as spam. I am leaving the question, but removed the link, please do not use it again or I'll have to remove the whole question.

Comment: Is rosé an acceptable compromise?

Answer (score 2):

Pinot noir is generally made as a light bodied red wine, and in many cases, tends to have enough acidity to make it a wonderful pairing with lots of different kinds of foods.  (Barberas from Italy are similar).  Knowing that red wine is not a traditional pairing for fish, I would go ahead and see if you like Pinot Noir with whatever fish you like.

Dry rosé (there are some lovely French, Spanish, and Italian dry rosés) is also a nice choice, as they are generally light, easy to drink wines.

Remember, what YOU like is the right wine for whatever you're eating, no matter what the experts say.

Comment: Yes, I have been to several restaurants where the sommelier has paired a red wine with a white fish (cod and seabass are the two I remember but there were more). The main thing is that you don't want a wine that is in any way tannic as it can leave a metallic taste in the mouth.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most memorable meals I ever ate was a seared halibut steak, with which I drank a slightly chilled Beaujolais (light, fruity, made from Gamay grape, if French wines aren't so readily available in your part of the world).  I did take the precaution of phoning the restaurant half an hour before I was due to arrive to ask them to put the Beaujolais on ice, to bring it down to about 15C (60F). That was 20 years ago, and I still reminisce about that meal.